# Cannot merge node using null property value for sourceID. (ICIJ Panama Papers Data)

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to import a csv file into Neo4j DB, here is the link for the CSV file 
http://apps.dealopia.com/offshoreleaks/offshore_leaks_csvs-20170104/Intermediaries.csv

The query that I am using to import the CSV data into DB is

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV FROM "http://apps.dealopia.com/offshoreleaks/offshore_leaks_csvs-20170104/Intermediaries.csv" AS line
MERGE (i:Intermediateries{name:line[1],internal_id:line[2],address:line[3],valid_until:line[4],country_codes:line[5],countries:line[6],status:line[7],node_id:line[8],sourceID:line[9]})
```

The Query produces the following error:-
**Cannot merge node using null property value for sourceID**

I found some useful resources but given the size of ICIJ Panama Papers Size it will take hours to execute, is there any way to eliminate checking for NULL values and optimize the query?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the indexing wrong. Index starts from 0, not 1. Also there is a header line in the given csv. So edit the Cypher query accordingly.

Change it to the following:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "http://apps.dealopia.com/offshoreleaks/offshore_leaks_csvs-20170104/Intermediaries.csv" AS line 
MERGE 
(i:Intermediateries{name:line[0],internal_id:line[1],address:line[2],valid_until:line[3],country_codes:line[4],countries:line[5],status:line[6],node_id:line[7],sourceID:line[8]})
```

See the official documentation for more details - http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/load-csv/#load-csv-import-data-from-a-csv-file

Answer (score 1):

yes you can easily filter out rows with sourceID null

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000 LOAD CSV FROM  "http://apps.dealopia.com/offshoreleaks/offshore_leaks_csvs-20170104/Intermediaries.csv" AS line 
WITH line where line[9] is not null
MERGE (i:Intermediateries{name:line[1],internal_id:line[2],address:line[3],
valid_until:line[4],country_codes:line[5],countries:line[6],status:line[7],node_id:line[8],sourceID:line[9]})
```

You can also use coalesce if you want to import those nodes, even though they do not have source ID

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000 LOAD CSV FROM  "http://apps.dealopia.com/offshoreleaks/offshore_leaks_csvs-20170104/Intermediaries.csv" AS line 
WITH line,coalesce(line[9],"NoId") as sourceID
MERGE (i:Intermediateries{name:line[1],internal_id:line[2],address:line[3],
valid_until:line[4],country_codes:line[5],countries:line[6],status:line[7],node_id:line[8],sourceID:sourceID})
```

I would create a query like this if I imported this if you have [apoc plugin](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures)

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM  "http://apps.dealopia.com/offshoreleaks/offshore_leaks_csvs-20170104/Intermediaries.csv" AS line 
MERGE (i:Intermediateries{internal_id:line.internal_id})
ON CREATE SET i += apoc.map.clean(row.properties,['internal_id'],[])
```

if you do not have apoc plugin you have to specify properties manually

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM  "http://apps.dealopia.com/offshoreleaks/offshore_leaks_csvs-20170104/Intermediaries.csv" AS line 
MERGE (i:Intermediateries{internal_id:line.internal_id})
ON CREATE SET i.name = line.name,i.address = line.address, i.valid_until = line.valid_until,
i.country_codes = line.country_code, i.countries = line.countries,i.status = line.status,i.node_id = line.node_id,
i.sourceID = line.sourceID,i.note = line.note
```

Comment: The problem persists with the query

Comment: The last one works for a while but returns error.
**Cannot merge node using null property value for internal_id**

Comment: The underlying problem here is that it´s impossible to merge nodes with null values. For instance `MERGE (a{key: value})` will always be impossible to do if value is null. The safe way is `MERGE (a) SET a.key = value` as the last example.

However in this case internal_id is the main identifier of the Intermediary, I assume, so we need some value there. I would STRONGLY suggest clean the data before importing, such as adding internal_id where needed or removing those lines. If this can´t be done, then a COALESCE(line.internal_id, name) could do the trick to use the name as internal_id.